# Add dynamic password_expirable duration for devise_security_extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using **devise_security_extension** gem for expire user password. But it expires the password after what the duration gave in config/initializers/devise.rb. I want to use the  duration that present in user table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem is not release with current master. When i installed this gem i got the version 0.9.2 and it doesn't have updated code. But the current master is updated with take value from instance level. So i cloned gem into local.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this line: [password_expirable.rb#L43](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/6fbf95fb262135584c1dae7a7756867c95a69752/lib/devise_security_extension/models/password_expirable.rb#L43)

```
def expire_password_after
  self.class.expire_password_after
end
```

If you override the `expire_password_after` in the model, it should do what you want.

**NOT Tested**